# Using callback function in websocket api javascript

Tags: javascript, websocket, promise, socket.io, callback

i have a websocket client using the websocket api for javascript and my server is using socket.io

I'm trying to put a callback function like this

**client js** *Using build in javascript WebSocket api*

```js
//im formatting the string like that because thats what socket.io needs for some reason

  var sendString = '42' + JSON.stringify(['checkLogin' , username, password])
    socket.send(sendString, function(returnData){
      console.log(returnData);
      resolve(returnData);
    })
```

but I keep getting an error that callback is not a function on my server-side using socket.io which looks like this

**server js** *using socket.io library*

```js
socket.on('checkLogin', function(username, password, callback){
  console.log(username, password)
  webUser.findOne({username:username}, function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs)
    if(docs){
      if(docs.password == password){
        callback(docs._id)
      }else{
        callback(false)
      }
    }
    if(!docs){
      callback(false)
    }
  });
})
```

what can i change to make this set the callback function correctly

Comment: Which websocket library  are you using?  Please post a link to the NPM page for the exact webSocket library you're using.

Comment: I'm using the websocket API built into the browser. I'm testing it would in an HTML file but for building tabris apps it's uses the same api

Comment: Server-side?  You said the error is "callback is not a function" ***server-side*** so I'm asking what library you're using on the server.  And, if you want help with a server-side error, you have to show us the relevant server-side code.  If the error is not on your server, please correct your question.

Comment: FYI, the  client-side `socket.send()` does not have a callback function as an argument.

Comment: so is there no way to achieve what I'm trying to do using the WebSockets API ? also I edited my question sorry about that I'm not feeling right today :(

Comment: First, you have to make your question clear.  What server-side webSocket library are you using?  I need to see the API of that library.  Why can you not answer that?  Are you using socket.io or plain webSocket?  If webSocket, which exact server-side library?

Comment: it says im using socket.io in the question when i talk about why i formated the string like that i said **im formatting the string like that because thats what socket.io needs for some reason**

Comment: Well, the question says both webSocket (in the title) and now I see socket.io in the body - didn't see that earlier.  It appears you're using the wrong API on the client side for your `.send()`.  If this is a socket.io connection, you need to be using the socket.io API on the client to send your message.

Comment: no worries sorry about the mixup like I said I'm not feeling well and thinking straight lol

Comment: You should be using `socket.emit()` to send data from either client or server if this is a socket.io connection.  That takes three arguments `socket.emit(msgName, data, callback)`.  The callback is optional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First problem.  If you're using socket.io on the server-side, you must be using a socket.io client.  You can't use a webSocket client with a socket.io server.  They won't connection.  This is true even though socket.io is using the webSocket transport underneath.  A socket.io server needs the socket.io layer on top of webSocket.

Second problem, to send data with a socket.io client, you would use either `socket.send()` when you are just sending raw data with no message name or you would use `socket.emit()` when you are sending a message name.

In your case, I would recommend you use this on the client:

```
 socket.emit('checkLogin', {username, password}, function(result => {
     console.log(result);
 });
```

And, then modify your server code like this:

```
socket.on('checkLogin', function(data, callback){
  let username = data.username;
  let password = data.password;
  console.log(username, password)
  webUser.findOne({username:username}, function(err, docs) {
    console.log(docs)
    if(docs){
      if(docs.password == password){
        callback(docs._id)
      }else{
        callback(false)
      }
    }
    if(!docs){
      callback(false)
    }
  });
})
```

Comment: i can do regular things like `socket.send('42' + JSON.stringify(['checkLogin' , username, password]));` and it works fine just getting a callback to work would be weird at first i wasn't able to get them to connect but using this `const socket = new WebSocket('ws://157.230.66.208:4343/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=websocket','chat-protocol');` works like a charm

Comment: @NicholasHendricks - If you're only going to use webSocket functionality, then use a webSocket server, not a socket.io server.  The whole point of using socket.io is to use the features that it adds above and beyond a plain webSocket.

Comment: ok I was just wondering if it was possible the whole reason I'm using the WebSocket API is that Tabris.js uses it and cant be used with socket.io-client sadly thanks for all of your help

Comment: @NicholasHendricks - If you want to program with webSocket, then change your server to a webSocket server and that will match with a webSocket client.  You will be limited to the features that the standard webSocket protocol supports.

Comment: socket.io is already used for the web clients and i want to keep it that way that's why I was trying to make a solution for using pure WebSockets with the socket.io server because Tabris does not support socket.io client at all and now that I cant use callbacks or anything like that I definitely won't be using pure WebSockets unless I kind find a way to implement callbacks in some way. thanks for the help.